# Which viewer can search within a line?

Tags: search

I have a file (a minified Javascript file) that is essentially one long line.

When I run a search in this file with `mc` (by pressing F7 in the builtin viewer) or with `less` (by typing a slash) apparently it takes me to the start of the line, even though wrapping is activated. That is not helpful.

Is there a commonly available (I'm using Ubuntu) viewer that can take me to the line *after wrapping* where the search term was found?

Comment: !viewer that can take me to the line` ... you said that there is only one line

Comment: you could use a text editor that had line-wrap capability

Answer (score 2):

`vim`'s and `nvi`'s implementations of `view` at least will scroll the wrapped line representation to let you see at least the start of the match (`set hls` in `~/.vimrc`/`~/.exrc` to highlight searches).

Use `view -` to view stdin (as in `seq 10000 | paste -sd ' ' - | view -` as an example of viewing an overlong line)

So will the `most` pager (with `-w` to wrap) and the `more` implementation from `util-linux`.

Comment: @zevzek, see `gj` or `g` `<down>` for that.